# Make a Scheduled Call to run One More time

Tags: java, multithreading

We have a scheduled task that runs every 10 seconds and a thread pool with 3 threads that actually update a static common map. Every 10 seconds the scheduled action prints this map.
The problem is that I want the scheduler to stop printing after the 3 threads finish with the map. But here is the key. I don't want to stop scheduler instantly, I want to print first ( the final version of the map) and then finishes.

```
public class myClass implements ThreadListener {
    public static ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>> wordOccurenceSet = new ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>();
    int numberOfThreads = 0;
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    public void getAnswer(Collection<CharacterReader> characterReaders, Outputter outputter) {




        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(characterReaders.size());
         OutputterWriteBatch scheduledThread = new OutputterWriteBatch(outputter,wordOccurenceSet);

        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(scheduledThread, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        for (CharacterReader characterReader : characterReaders) {
            NotifyingRunnable runnable = new CharacterReaderTask(characterReader, wordOccurenceSet);
            runnable.addListener(this);

            executor.execute(runnable);
        }



    }


    @Override
    public void notifyRunnableComplete(Runnable runnable) {
        numberOfThreads += 1;
        if(numberOfThreads == 3 ){
         //All threads finished...  What can I do to terminate after one more run?
        }
    }
}
```

The Listener actually just get notified when a thread finishes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make your `numberOfThreads` synchronized. You don't want it to become corrupted when two `Reader` threads finish concurrently. It's a primitive int so it *may* not be corruptable (i am not that proficient with JVM), but the general rules of thread safety should be followed anyway.

```
// 1. let finish OutputterWriteBatch if currently running
scheduler.shutdown(); 
// 2. will block and wait if OutputterWriteBatch was currently running
scheduler.awaitTermination(someReasonableTimeout);
// 3. one more shot.
scheduler.schedule(scheduledThread,0);
// You could also run it directly if your outputting logic in run()
// is published via separate method, but i don't know the API so i suppose
// only Runnable is published
```

But this shouldn't be called directly from `notifyRunnableComplete`, of course. The listener method is called from your `Reader` threads, so it would block the last one of 3 threads from finishing timely. Rather make a notification object which some other thread will `wait()` on (preferably the one which executed `getAnswer()`), `notify()` it when `numberOfThreads` reaches 3 and put the above code after the `wait()`.

Oh, and when `wait()` unblocks, you should double check that `numberOfThreads` is really 3, if not, cycle back to `wait()`. Google "spurious wakeup" to explanation why this is needed.